# Pass row value in props through <Link> to new tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props

In my React application, when clicking a row in bootstrap table, I need to pass the value, `row.testid` to the new tab followed.

I learned that value cannot be passed in the state. Can we use **local storage** to pass the variable? Or, is there any other way to pass it on?

```js
column1 = (cell, row) => {
    let link = `${cell}`
    return (
        <Link to={{                
          pathname: "/test/${row.testid}"      
        }} target="_blank" rel='noopener noreferrer'>
          {cell}
        </Link>
}


Renderpart
=========

return (
            <div>
         <BootstrapTable data={}>
                .......
         </BootstrapTable>
       <BrowserRouter>               
       <Route exact path="/test/:id" component={testcomp} />               
        </BrowserRouter>
       </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use **withRouter** of **react-router**

```
<Link to={`/test/${row.testid}`} target="_blank" rel='noopener noreferrer' >
  {cell}
</Link>
```

In **testcomp** you can get **params** using **props.match.params**
please use **react-router** as HOC

> import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
>
> export default withRouter(testcomp);
>
> this.props.match.params.rowid

**Update :**

```
<Route exact path="/test/:id" component={testcomp} />
// path match.params.id will depends on path params of /test/:params
```

Please use **this.props.match.params.id** if you are using **id in Route**.
for ex. if you use **path="/test/:id" so use params.id** and if you are using **path="/test/:rowid" so use params.rowid**

Comment: Hi,couldnt do it,since i need to mock the table data.can you confirm whether it can be achieved using localstorage.If so,any sample code pls.

Comment: @shiju **localstorage** is not good approach,  i will recommend to use ** react-router** and there is noway that **react-router** is not working i am using this method and i know you can get **rowid** from **match**

Comment: Updated the code,along the below code in Testcomp,                                            import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

export default withRouter(testcomp);

Comment: yes, i did.Can we fetch the value(his.props.match.params.id), in componentDidMount or in constructor method?

Comment: @shiju you can get params values in both componentDidMount and constructor

Answer (score -1):

Atlast my code worked,changed the code as {{ pathname: `/test/${row.testid}` }}
 -->   /test/${row.testid}}.

Thanks all for your help.

Updated Code:

column1 = (cell, row) => {
    let link = `${cell}`
    return (
        
        }} target="_blank" rel='noopener noreferrer'>
          {cell}
        
}

## Renderpart

return (
            
         
                .......
         
       
       
        
       
);